# Yeast Attenuation

Tags: yeast, attenuation

Does the percentage attenuation of the yeast, directly match the fermentability of the wort, ie, If i am after a one fifth gravity beer, then that has attenuated by 80% .   so is the spirit indication and ash content taken into consideration for the final gravity result? As I see that yeasts can vary widely in there purported attenuation. from low 65% to high 80%. So, how do I match the fermentability of the wort with a particular attentive yeast strain, in order to get a one fifth gravity beer?   Is there a chart for this? And if I were to use malt that had a percentage fermentability of 64%, with a yeast with  a 70% attenuation, would I result in a one fifth gravity beer?

Comment: What are you trying to communicate with "one fifth gravity"? Are you looking at the 80% attenuation and figuring that the beer after fermentation will be the remaining 20% (1/5)? I.e. one fifth of the original gravity?

Comment: Yes,thats it, So how come the yeasts ability expressed also in percentage, doesnt match up?

Comment: Because the yeast attenuation relates to what the yeast is able to eat, and the wort fermentability related to how much of it edible. Think if it like this: you go to a banquet where most of the food is real, but some is fake (say 20% is fake). That's the fermentability. You, however, have a limited appetite, so you can't finish all of the real food, no matter how hard you try. The amount to of food you can eat is the yeast's attenuation.

Comment: I see ,so on an average DME , if I use 04 yeast , then I will be looking at a final gravity of circa 33% of the OG. ?

Comment: Can you show your working on that?

Comment: S-04 has an attenuation of 72-75%, so if you have a normal wort composition, you should expect your final gravity to be OG-(OGx72-75). You can raise or lower the final gravity a little bit by adjusting the fermentability of the wort. However, increasing the fermentability beyond the limit of the yeast's attenuation will not increase the attenuation, as the yeast stop eating. Conversely, if your wort is not fermentable enough, you will never reach the stated attenuation.

Comment: Correct, I picked the wrong yeast strain there, I meant one with an attenuation of circa 67%.   But anyway, if my wort is 75% fermentable and i use say Mangrove Jacks M36, circa 75% atten, then i would only get 75% of 75% atten', you say?

Comment: No, they don't stack like that. If you have a 100% fermentable wort and you pitch 75% attenuation yeast, you'll get 75% attenuation. If you have 80% wort and pitch 75% yeast, you'll still get 75% attenuation. If you have 60% wort and pitch 75% yeast, you'll only get 60% attenuation. Google "limit of attenuation test" and read up about how it works and why it's a useful test.

Comment: OK, I have been looking at this from the opposite end ,the wort end design.I have only just discovered the different yeast properties.

Comment: I understand. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there is nothing like a one fifth gravity beer. 1/5 = 0.2, which means nothing in terms of fermentation.

Your question must be answered in three parts, the first part being what are you measuring, how it is done, and what the results say, and the second part is about the work the yeast does, and the third about fermentability.

The hydrometer is your basic tool, which measures the density of a sugary water solution. When you measure 1.000, then you have pure water. When you measure in a solution with sugar then this number increases.

Before fermenting (after the boil), you measure the original gravity (OG). After the fermentation you measure the final gravity (FG). From this, the apparent attenuation is derived by the formula (OG - FG) / (OG - 1).

This is called the apparent attenuation. The reason for this is that the solution now also contains alcohol in addition to water and sugar. This has as a consequence that the liquid density (alcohol + water) is now less than that of water, and your hydrometer actually sinks lower.

So, to answer already part of your question: "spirit indication" is not taken into consideration, nor are other solids in solution.

Now for the second part. Wort is actually a very complex solution of all kinds of different sugars, in different kinds of concentrations depending upon the different malts used.

The attenuation of yeasts is influenced by two parameters: the number of different sugars that yeast can ferment and their flocculation, the rate of dropping to the bottom of the fermentation vessel.

The attenuation given by the producer of the yeast mostly indicates if yeasts will consume more differentiated sugars, and are, as a result, capable of attaining a higher attenuation.

However, this is also influenced by the flocculation. When the yeasts drop out of the beer, there will be less fermentation as a result. If it would be possible to regularly rouse the yeast, then fermentation would go on (in England they used to do this, certain English yeast strains drop out rather fast, and the brewers would then roll the casks where the beer was kept to get better attenuation).

You can influence the fermentability of your wort by playing with the mash temperatures, but there are no hard and fast rules.

There are two enzymes in the mash, alfa-amylase and beta-amylase, which convert starches to complex and simple sugars. Alfa-amylase works best on starches, but its optimal temperature is around 70° C. Beta-amylase works best in converting complex sugars to simple sugars, but it works best at 64° C. These enzymes don't last in the mash, because they are denatured by the temperature of the mash. This takes its time of course, but the higher the temperature, the faster they are denatured.

What does this mean for fermentability? A rule of thumb is that mashing for a long time at 64° C will create a very fermentable wort, while mashing at higher temperatures will decrease the fermentability.

However, it's not possible to put figures on this, i.e. if you mash at this temperature, you will get this kind of fermentability is not something that can be put into tables.

My experience is that most yeasts do ferment wort in the ranges given by the producer.

So, if the only thing you have is a particularly attenuating yeast, then mash at higher temperature, e.g. 67° C or 68° C, and see what happens to your FG.

Comment: I am afraid, that after reading your answer, I shall have to ask the question in a different way.

Comment: A one fifth gravity beer is one which has a final gravity that is 20% of the start gravity. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Everything Chthon said is sound, but to put it a little more concisely, fermentability and attenuation are two unrelated things.

Wort fermentablility refers to what proportion of the wort consists of fermentable sugars.

Attenuation refers to what percentage of available fermentable sugars a yeast strain will typically ferment.

The two things are both important factors in determining final gravity, but they do not actually affect one another.

Does that help you at all?

Comment: i already know this.

Comment: Then you should know the answer to your original question "Does the percentage attenuation of the yeast, directly match the fermentability of the wort?" The answer is no, because the two things are entirely unrelated.

Comment: Tell me why.....

Comment: I did tell you why, in the answer above. I've also just given you an analogy in the comments of your OP

Comment: I mean, why they should at least not match up?

Comment: I don't understand why you think they should match up? They're governed by entirely unrelated factors! As in the analogy above, your hunger level has literally zero relation to how much food the cook prepares. The weather of a given day has nothing to do with how much you want it to rain. There's no link. The two things combine to affect the outcome of the fermentation, but that's the only connection they share.

Comment: Can you tell me why they should match up? Show your reasoning and explain it to me very clearly. Once I know where you've gotten mixed up, I can help you through it.

Comment: At least match up, being a 'short' comment.  Should not the yeast at least have the ability to consume all the available fermentable malt?

Comment: As cthon said, flocculation causes them to drop out before they've finished. If yeast consistently consumed all available sugars, there would be no need for an attenuation rating for yeast. Clearly, yeast do not routinely ferment all available sugars.

Comment: So a wort of 75% fermentability, with a yeast of 75% attenuation, is going to end up mighty sweet/sticky,you say?

Comment: That's not the question you've been asking.

Comment: Connected reasoning?

Comment: Only vaguely, and I still think you haven't read the answer properly. Attenuation is a measurement based on the gravity of the whole wort, not just the portion that is fermentable. If you have a yeast that has 75% attenuation and you pitch it into any wort with a fermentability between 75 and 100%, you should expect the final gravity to be OG-(OGx75%). As long as fermentability is higher than attenuation, the beer will be normal.

Comment: All I know is that the degree of apparent attenuation you achieve,depends not only on the yeast strain,but on your wort fermentability. I am trying to discern the differences in this joint venture re' their respective attenuations.Sorry if you dont understand my question.Leave it at that now.